# Lock a specific UI item from phone orientation change?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to lock a specific UI element from rotating during the orientation change?

I am developing a Camera application and I want to retain my ViewFinder VideoBrush to be in landscape mode always.

Setting SupportedOrientations="Landscape" wouldn't solve my problem, since I want all the other control on the screen to be rotated according to orientation. (Controls such as Camera button in the application bar, text written on the screen etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to watch the current [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and place the VideoBrush accordingly for each possibility.